# What does this activity record of gmail mean, when it says an authorized application with IP from India?

Tags: ip, gmail

There is a record in my Gmail's activity:

```
Access Type :
    Authorized Application (860033281504.apps.googleusercontent.com) Hide details
    "name: Yahoo Mail Client"
    "vendor: Yahoo"
    "version: 1.0 1458656085"
    OAuth Domain Name:
    860033281504.apps.googleusercontent.com
    Manage Account Access

Location (IP address)
    India (74.6.109.229)    

Date/Time
    5:36 pm (0 minutes ago)
```

I have never been to India, and have been in US. But https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/74.6.109.229 shows the IP is from US. Should I worry about my gmail account being hacked?

What does the record mean?

I am using yahoo mail app on android to access my gmail account, besides using gmail's webmail to access gmail.

Thanks.

Comment: I would say this is a fault of GMail but to be 100% safe, try to change your password. I dont think you are Hacked. Google normally informs you if someone is logging in from a completely different country and will ask for another confirmation

Answer (score 2):

The accessor claimed to be "Yahoo Mail Client", so either it had to do with you using the Yahoo Mail Client, or coincidentally an attacker also used the Yahoo Mail Client while accessing your account.

The IP address shown (74.6.109.229) seems to be owned by Yahoo: https://db-ip.com/all/74.6.109. It's really unlikely that it is an attacker accessing your account (unless they're coincidentally doing it through a Yahoo server).

Another geo-IP database shows the IP as being in California (https://www.ultratools.com/tools/geoIpResult), so it's probably safe to disregard the detail in the message from Google claiming that the access was from India. Chances are that Gmail is just operating with an old geo-IP database. (Though even if it is from India, it seems to be from an IP block owned by Yahoo, so it would still likely be an Indian Yahoo server.)